# IE not letting me set a textarea value with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, dom, textarea

I'm trying to change the `value` on a `<textarea>` element. This code works great in Firefox, but IE claims there's an error `onblur` and doesn't set the value.

```
<textarea 
    name="comment" 
    id="comment" 
    rows="8" 
    cols="80"
    style="color:grey;" 
    onfocus="if(this.value=='Add a comment...') {this.style.color='black'; this.value='';}"
    onblur="if(this.value=='') {this.style.color='grey'; this.value='Add a comment...';}">Add a comment...</textarea>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can this be causing the problem -

> this.style.color='grey'

?

```
this.style.color='gray';
```

Whole Code:

```
<textarea name="comment" id="comment" rows="8" cols="80" style="color: gray;" onfocus="if(this.value=='Add a comment...') {this.style.color='black'; this.value='';}"
        onblur="if(this.value=='') {this.style.color='gray'; this.value='Add a comment...';}">Add a comment...</textarea>
```

Comment: Most likely, they are American Colour names ;)

Comment: Yep - Its American COLOR names :)